# Is initializing a vector of empty values more efficient than just calling `push_back()`?

Tags: c++, constructor

So, I want to avoid constantly `push_back()`-ing because I know that it is inefficient.

Say that I have a class `Network` that takes a `const std::vector<int>& topology`. It has a `std::vector<Layer> layers` property that is created using this topology. The number of `layers` that are created is equal to the `.size()` of the `topology` vector passed to the constructor for `Network`.

Say, however, that `Layer` itself has a property `std::vector<Neuron>`, and that the `Layer` constructor takes a `int neuronCount` that is equal to each individual `int` in the `toplogy` and creates a `Neuron` with a random `value` property by default.

Now, is it better to initialize the `layers` vector with a size in the constructor initializer list (i.e. `Network::Network(const std::vector<int>& topology): layers(topology.size())` using a `default` constructor for `Layer` containing 0 `Neuron`s) and to then call `emplace_back()` in the constructor body when actually creating the `Neuron`s in the layer, or is it just as inefficient as calling `push_back()`

Or, worse yet, am I missing the mark completely here? I'm new to C++ as well as the subject matter of the application I'm building, so I'd put money on the hypothesis that I'm missing something here....

Comment: Using `vector::reserve` would let vector preallocate capacity if you know how much you want. Then `push_back` won't cause allocation when it doesn't exceeed capacity. In short, `push_back` might not impact performance.

Comment: _because I know that it is inefficient_  Have you profiled your code?

Comment: @Eljay No I have not, but I know that by default `push_back()` creates a new `vector` each time it is called. Right?

Comment: @LouisGo You know.... I think that might be what I'm looking for... I vaguely remember that method call from something I had read. Learning languages, eh? But will this work as efficiently when the vector's members will end up growing in size? You'll notice that each member contains it's own vector of classes and these vectors are not pointers

Comment: @LouisGo How would I go about calling that in either the constructor initializer list or the constructor? Isn't that typically called when the vector itself is declared? How does that work with a class property?

Comment: It depends on whether you want default-initialized values or not. If not, `preserve` costs less.

Comment: If you already know the size initializing is more efficient as push_back allocates needed  memory

Comment: _I know that by default push_back() creates a new vector each time it is called. Right?_  No, that is incorrect.

Comment: @LouisGo As stated, since there are nested vectors, the size of the nested vectors is unknown until the body of the constructor.

Comment: @Eljay Really? I must be reading this wrong: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/ says "which causes an automatic reallocation of the allocated storage space if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity." Does this *not* mean that a new vector is created elsewhere in memory, if there's not enough free bytes after the current vector? If so, could you please translate and give me a reference doc? This would be very good to know!

Comment: My suggestion is elaborate on your context. Eg; if there are known average size or system restriction for memory ..etc.

Comment: "if -and only if- the new vector size surpasses the current vector capacity.", @Eljay means it's not "always". It depends on capacity which I stated in my answer.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, I see. As stated in my question, I do know the *size* of the nested vector when the top-level class `Network` is constructed. In this case, there is no average size. I probably should have added that details, I suppose, I apologize :(

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 -- The authors of the vector class are well aware that it is naive to actually allocate memory on every call to `push_back`, even without a call to `reserve`.  So they build in a strategy where `push_back` will less likely cause an allocation.  The strategy may be to allocate 1.5 times the current size whenever an allocation occurs.  The `reserve` can be used to guarantee contiguity and the memory always remaining in one spot, but it may not be all that it's cracked up to be when it comes to efficiency.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes, that makes it a bit more clear I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `push_back` causes re-allocation only when size exceeds capacity.

If your concern is preallocation "might" impact performace, then using `vector::reserve` would let vector preallocate capacity if you know how much you want. Then push_back won't cause allocation when it doesn't exceed capacity.

However if you don't know the length of your data, `reserve` is not suitable. So use it judiciously.

Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

The example in cppreference: https://godbolt.org/z/PcYjWj

---

Between setting size in ctor or `reserve`, it depends on whether you need default-initialized value or not.

Comment: So, in this case, when each element in the vector contains a nested vector of elements, should `reserve` be used?

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 It depends on context. Does nested elements has an average size? If yes, spending more memory for less time by `reserve` would be a choice.

Comment: That's a good point. In this case, it does not have an "average" size, *per se*. I could not estimate the size, but it *is* known. As stated, it is passed in the vector `topology`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point in your quest. If the amount of `neuron` is the same as the amount of `layer`. `reserve` is a good choice, because value is unknown and wasting time to initialize it in vector is unnecessary.

Comment: Is there an efficient way to pass this nested vector size down the class chain? I know the nested vector's size at the time that the top-level class is constructed, so is there a way to pass this down the chain effectively?

Comment: No worries, man :) No, the vector sizes are *not* the same. However, as stated, we have two vectors: a vector of size 3 (`layers`) and three vectors of size `3`, `2,` and `3`, respectively, where they are 3 layers, and the layers' member vectors `neurons` are size `3`, `2`, and `3` :). I must mention that these vector sizes are adjustable, as the `topology` pram where they come from is a parameter of the top-level class `Network`

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 The most common way is pass the size in ctor of `neuron` which should be suffice... What's the efficience you want for passing `int size`? Since primitive type is small enough, pass by value is as good as pass by reference. Also you might write another question for it with code snippet. Then it'll get better answsers.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. While I did describe that the `int`s are use to construct a number of more complex classes, I probably did not give enough code. I should have added complete classes.